# Is sailing performance polar possible with polar chart type

Tags: angular, performance, charts, chart.js

I’m wondering if it would be possible to achieve similar results  with the polar chart or another chart type.

[https://48north.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/Farr-40-from-Farr-copy.png](Polar chart sample)

The data is recorded by wind speed increments. Ex. 5, 8, 11, 15, etc. With values for each increments that includes:

- boat speed, compas angle

Thanks

Looking at the polar chart samples this does not appear to be possible.

Comment: It's possible, but it's not as simple as providing the data and some options. It would be rather complicated to customize the [`radar`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/area/radar.html) chart controller for that, so I suppose the simplest way would be to make a (cartesian) [line chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html) and draw the polar grid "manually" in a [plugin](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html).